# How to connect to multiple PostgreSQL schemas from Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-schema, postgis, geodjango

In my GeoDjango project I want to connect to a legacy PostgreSQL/PostGIS database. It contains the following schemas:

- data // contains all the geospatial data
- django // empty, created by me
- public // system tables such as `spatial_ref_sys`

I want the Django tables shown in the screenshot to go into the `django` schema. I do not want to pollute the `public` schema.

[image: Django tables]

I want the "data" models to connect to the `data` schema. I already tried to [generate models from the legacy tables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/) but `python manage.py inspectdb` connects to the `public` schema.

---

In order to provide access to the different schemas I adapted the [approach 2 of this article](http://blog.amvtek.com/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/) which preassigns individual `search_path` values to specific database users:

```
-- user accessing django schema...
CREATE ROLE django_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'secret';
ALTER ROLE django_user SET search_path TO django, public;

-- user accessing data schema...
CREATE ROLE data_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'secret';
ALTER ROLE data_user SET search_path TO data, public;
```

Then I configured the database connections as follows:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
            'USER': 'django_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
    },

    'data': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
            'USER': 'data_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
    },
}
```

How can I actually configure that Django uses the `django` schema while "data" models connect to the `data` schema?

---

#### Readings

- [How to use schemas in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160598/how-to-use-schemas-in-django)
- [How to specify schema name while running "syncdb" in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680673/how-to-specify-schema-name-while-running-syncdb-in-django)
- [Issue #6148 - Add generic support for database schemas](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148#no2)

Comment: See [Automatic database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)

Comment: @falsetru The documentation for automatic database router does not mention how to deal with multiple schemas in the one database.

Comment: @JJD Did you found the answer on this problem? Thank you!

Comment: @AbzRockers Only what you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39322184/356895).

Comment: @JJD Thank you for the response! I think you should mark it the right answer if it solved your problem, I neglected the answers on this question because it has no marked right answer and no up votes as well.

Answer (score 10):

You have to leverage the `search_path`:

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'OPTIONS' : {
                'options': '-c search_path=django,public'
            },
            'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
            'USER': 'django_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
    },

    'data': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'OPTIONS' : {
                'options': '-c search_path=data,public'
            },
            'NAME': 'multi_schema_db',
            'USER': 'data_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
    },
}
```

- Source: [Accessing multiple Postgres schemas from Django](https://www.amvtek.com/blog/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need to manage the tables through migrations, you could use **escaped quotes** for the `db_table` attribute of your model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
    class Meta():
        managed=False
        db_table=u'"schema\".\"table"'
```

Comment: This worked for me.
You can simply use without escaped quotes too.
`db_table='schema"."table'`

Comment: This is great, and as far as I can tell, its working with migrations too!

Comment: did not work for me nor with quotes neither without

Comment: **It worked for me** without `managed=False` and creating only the schema in the database before running any migrations.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Django Tenant Schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) with great success. It allows you to access different schemas by delineating different tenants as the owners of the schemas.

This will allow you to set the schema on a per call basis. If the schema needs to be set on a per url basis, you can do that in middleware.